# How do I make this shorter in my terminal?

Tags: git, github, terminal

`git add .; git commit -m 'MESSAGE'; git push origin master`

Is a long thing to remember... Is there a way I can make it so I just have to type in e.g. `gitcommit -'MESSAGE'` ? I tried using `alias`,but I don't know how to do the `-'MESSAGE'` part...

P.s. I'm on osx, if that's relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases don't handle parameters, but functions do:

```
gitcommit () {
    # set -e
    git add .
    git commit -m "$1"
    git push origin master
}
```

I'd probably add `set -e` to the function, as you don't want git to commit if the addition wasn't successful.

You can add the function definition to your `.bashrc` or `.bashprofile` file to have it available everytime you start the shell.

Comment: Okay, so I put the function in the terminal, and how do I call it? gitcommit("MESSAGE") ?

Comment: And where do I `set -e` ?

Comment: For convenience, you can always create an alias that calls the function (or script) in question.

Answer (score 2):

When you are on linux then write a bash function. To do all that in one line.

```
function gcommit {
    git add .
    git commit -m "$1"
    git push origin master
}
```

Put that in your `~/.bash_profile` then you can use the command as follow:

```
#gcommit "Your message"
```

Answer (score 2):

Install zshell on your terminal and you will get very short aliases for the commands like ga . for git add . and gca -m "message" for git commit and ggpush and ggpull for git push and git pull. Here is the tutorial to install http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/iTerm/zsh.html

Comment: Still, @choroba's `gitcommit "message"` is shorter ;)

Comment: Yes its shorter if you just want to push code to master or any specific branch. I am rails programmer and I found zshell very helpful :)